# How to LEFT JOIN two simple tables but not throwing away data from the second table?

Tags: sql

My SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/350efb/3

I am trying to LEFT JOIN two tables, and filter their values in my query. However, there are rows in the second table that have no matching in first table. I would like to return `NULL` if there are missing rows.

Expected result is:

```
oid bid name              oid    uid  value
1   1   Book 1  Name 1    1      1    User 1 OID 1
2   1   Book 1  Name 2    NULL   NULL NULL
3   1   Book 1  Name 3    NULL   NULL NULL
4   1   Book 1  Name 4    NULL   NULL NULL
5   1   Book 1  Name 5    5      1    User 1 OID 5
```

However, in my actual results as seen in the link, I only got two rows. All my rows with a NULL were not returned.

**Q:** How to achieve my expected output? I tried to add `OpeningUser.uid is NULL` but it didn't work.

My current query is:

```
select * from Opening
LEFT JOIN OpeningUser ON Opening.oid = OpeningUser.oid
WHERE Opening.bid=1 AND (OpeningUser.uid=1 OR OpeningUser.uid is NULL)
ORDER BY Opening.oid
```

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I'd guess you're having right side table conditions in the WHERE clause? Move such to the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh It's in the link.

Comment: I made 100% reproducible example.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/350efb/6

Comment: Great, but remember that SO is an archive, and the sqlfiddle will be gone a long time before SO.

Comment: @jarlh you were right anyway.

Comment: Just in case you hadn't realised, the link I posted in my earlier comment is a working solution to your question.